# Making an animation of a rotating cone, previous frame doesn't get erased

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have been making an animation of a cone rotating around a certain axis using funcAnimation from matplotlib. However, when the animation happens, the previous cone doesn't get deleted from the previous frame, so the result is a continuous flow of cones.

Does anyone know how I can remove the cone I plotted? I used ax.plot().

I plot each point of the cone separately like so:

```
for n, z in enumerate(zvec):
        x = lcone * z * np.array([cos(q) for q in theta])
        y = lcone * z * np.array([sin(q) for q in theta])
        xr, yr, zr = dot(rot12, array([x,y,z]))
        ln=ax.plot(xr, yr, zr, 'b-', lw=3, alpha=0.5)
```

So I guess the question is how to remove a bunch of these points together?

Also, if you have any other suggestions for making a cone rotating about an axis, that would be very helpful.

Comment: please provide us a code, we can only guess what you have done now

Answer (score 0):

With the aproach you are taking, you need to completly clear the plot before drawing again. I'd suggest writing the code as

```
for n, z in enumerate(zvec):
        x = lcone * z * np.array([cos(q) for q in theta])
        y = lcone * z * np.array([sin(q) for q in theta])
        xr, yr, zr = dot(rot12, array([x,y,z]))
        
        plt.clf() #clears entire frame

        ln=ax.plot(xr, yr, zr, 'b-', lw=3, alpha=0.5) #draw the new cone
```

You should see the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.clf) for the method.

Also Matplotlib also supports animations with a dedicated module, maybe take a look [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/animation_api.html).